# Is there a better option than the Singleton pattern for exposing my classes' dependencies, if I'm not using an IoC container?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, singleton, inversion-of-control

I am building a class library to be consumed by other applications. I do not have an IoC container as I do not wish to force it on the consumers of my library.

Consumers should be able to configure the library in their bootstrapper, as per this example:

```
Example.Configure({ x => 
    {
        x.AddSomeSetting();
        x.AddAnotherSetting();
    });
```

Any future use of the library should use this central configuration:

```
// exampleObject should use the central configuration defined above
var exampleObject = new Example.SomeClass();
```

I have used a singleton class to store the configuration, which is accessed by the rest of the library in future.

The problem comes when unit testing. As soon as a unit test method modifies the singleton configuration, all of the other unit tests are affected by this modification.

I could have a `Reset()` method on the singleton that is called at the start of each test, but it would be there purely for the test.

Is there a better solution than storing this global state as a singleton?

Comment: IMO the `Reset` method could also make sense for your users if the user wants to reconfigure the library...

Comment: @chrfin that's a good point.

Comment: You could use [static gateway](http://codebetter.com/jpboodhoo/2007/10/15/the-static-gateway-pattern/) instead of singleton.

Comment: Why do the unit tests use this singleton configuration at all? (i.e., why don't they instantiate their SUTs directly?)

Comment: @Sinatr I like how that pattern gives you the ability to effectively mock out a singleton. However, it doesn't address the other problem with singletons: that they are basically hidden dependencies. (e.g., the code compiles just fine if you don't call `Log.InitializeLogFactory`, yet there are classes that are explicitly dependent on it being configured.)

Comment: you can have Test set up and test clean up after each test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple: provide an instance of the configuration to each library component in its constructor. That might be a little more verbose than you want, but it meets your design goal and it gives the library user complete freedom (maybe even to use a dependency injection library themselves).

Comment: This would mean that the user of my library would need to pass this config in in the constructor when they instantiate any of the classes in my library?

Comment: Yes, they would need to do that. That's the cost of decoupling. On the bright side, your users will have total control over what they pass in. (Sorry for the late reply.)